# How do I install csvkit on Mac OS Big Sur?

Tags: homebrew, http-status-code-404, macos-big-sur, csvkit

I'm trying to install csvkit on my Mac (OS 11.7.7).  However, I'm getting this 404 error

```
$ brew install csvkit
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404                                                                             

Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --user-agent Homebrew/4.0.24-19-g1c081f3\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 11.7.7\)\ curl/7.87.0 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --progress-bar --location --remote-time --output /Users/davea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/api/cask.jws.json --compressed --speed-limit 100 --speed-time 5 --progress-bar https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json` exited with 22. Here's the output:
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
```

Attempting to upgrade via homebrew results in 404s as well

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R davea:admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Enumerating objects: 354, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (291/291), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (102/102), done.
remote: Total 194 (delta 64), reused 178 (delta 52), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (194/194), 293.69 KiB | 2.58 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (64/64), completed with 16 local objects.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
 * [new branch]          dependabot/bundler/Library/Homebrew/json_schemer-0.2.25 -> origin/dependabot/bundler/Library/Homebrew/json_schemer-0.2.25
 * [new branch]          dependabot/bundler/Library/Homebrew/parser-3.2.2.3 -> origin/dependabot/bundler/Library/Homebrew/parser-3.2.2.3
HEAD is now at 1c081f379 Merge pull request #15572 from razvanazamfirei/add-emoji-audit
Error: Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json!
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --user-agent Homebrew/4.0.24-19-g1c081f3\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 11.7.7\)\ curl/7.87.0 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --progress-bar --location --remote-time --output /Users/davea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/api/cask.jws.json --compressed --speed-limit 100 --speed-time 5 --progress-bar --silent https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json` exited with 22.
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

**Edit:** Here's what brew confnig reveals ...

```
$ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 4.0.24-19-g1c081f3
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 1c081f379dcaa2e8e6eb055edc49fe2e0457862b
Last commit: 7 days ago
Core tap origin: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: a3e0fb3fe4a28d59c4f0fc68198e3aab24a12be8
Core tap last commit: 4 months ago
Core tap branch: HEAD
Core tap JSON: 21 Jun 21:01 UTC
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_DISPLAY: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.UU9eGSZiOw/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.10 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.10_1/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Clang: 12.0.5 build 1205
Git: 2.39.2 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.87.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 11.7.7-x86_64
CLT: 12.5.0.22.9
Xcode: N/A
```

**Edit 2:** Adding output in response to suggestion given

```
$ HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install csvkit
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
==> Updated Homebrew from 4.0.24 (1c081f379) to 4.0.26 (9a482dea2).
Updated 6 taps (phinze/cask, homebrew/core, homebrew/cask, homebrew/services, mongodb/brew and spring-io/tap).
==> New Formulae
aarch64-elf-gdb                 forgit                          libvisual-projectm              scip
access                          form                            libwpe                          scrapy
ada-url                         garble                          libzen                          service-weaver
adr-viewer                      gat                             llvm@15                         shodan
aftman                          gcc@12                          lowdown                         shub
aichat                          getmail6                        lpeg                            shush
aicommits                       gffread                         ls-lint                         sickchill
aiven-client                    gfold                           mariadb@10.10                   sing-box
alass                           git-big-picture                 mariadb@10.11                   slsa-verifier
aliyunpan                       git-credential-oauth            mdt                             smartdns
amber                           git-tools                       melange                         solhint
animdl                          gitoxide                        meta-package-manager            spotify_player
ansible@7                       gmssl                           millet                          sql-migrate
apko                            go-feature-flag-relay-proxy     minigraph                       ssocr
ares                            go@1.19                         mods                            staq
argparse                        golines                         musikcube                       streamvbyte
arjun                           gotestsum                       nerdfix                         svlint
arttime                         grpc@1.54                       nexttrace                       svls
ast-grep                        grype                           nixpacks                        swift-outdated
ata                             gyb                             notify                          tailwindcss-language-server
aws-amplify                     hck                             ntfy                            teip
aws-sso-cli                     hexer                           ocmtoc                          tern
base16384                       hivex                           octobuild                       thriftgo
bashate                         hq                              okta-aws-cli                    tkey-ssh-agent
benerator                       hz                              ol                              tracy
blocky                          imessage-exporter               opal                            trippy
boolector                       ipget                           openai-whisper                  trurl
cargo-generate                  jet                             openfga                         trust-dns
cffi                            joern                           openiked                        tt
charls                          johnnydep                       openssl@3.0                     typescript-language-server
chatblade                       joshuto                         ord                             typical
clifm                           jsign                           pfetch-rs                       typst
clipboard                       jsmn                            pgvector                        ulfius
clive                           judy                            phoneinfoga                     victoriametrics
cloudpan189-go                  keyring                         picotool                        virtualfish
conan@1                         kitex                           pmtiles                         votca
conda-lock                      ksops                           pocketbase                      vscode-langservers-extracted
conduit                         lacework-cli                    poke                            vulkan-extensionlayer
convco                          leetup                          portal                          vulkan-tools
core-lightning                  libabigail                      procps@3                        vulkan-validationlayers
cppinsights                     libansilove                     protobuf@21                     vvdec
ddns-go                         libclc                          pycparser                       vvenc
debugbreak                      libdvbcsa                       pygit2                          wally
define                          libecpint                       pypy3.10                        wazero
devcontainer                    libfastjson                     pypy3.9                         wpebackend-fdo
dexter                          libgedit-gtksourceview          python-toml                     wxlua
dtools                          libgit2@1.5                     quantum++                       wzprof
dutree                          libint                          renovate                        xbyak
dzr                             liblxi                          resvg                           xurls
elfx86exts                      libmediainfo                    rio                             yamlfmt
enchive                         libomemo-c                      roblox-ts                       zchunk
erdtree                         libpaho-mqtt                    rojo                            zlint
fastgron                        libpaper                        rye                             zls
ffmpeg@5                        libvisual                       sad                             zpaqfranz
flavours                        libvisual-plugins               safeint                         zrok
==> New Casks
115                                                             logitech-camera-settings
1kc-razer                                                       logitech-g-hub
active-trader-pro                                               logitech-options
alex313031-thorium                                              logitune
alipay-key-tool                                                 loupedeck
apple-hewlett-packard-printer-drivers                           macwhisper
archaeology                                                     mediainfoex
asix-ax88179                                                    mfiles
audiocupcake                                                    minisim
bazecor                                                         mist
beardie                                                         moneymanager
bloop                                                           morgen
bluos-controller                                                motu-m-series
bookletcreator                                                  mullvad-browser
bose-updater                                                    multiviewer-for-f1
bruno                                                           mumu-x
caldigit-docking-utility                                        music-miniplayer
caldigit-thunderbolt-charging                                   music-remote
cameracontroller                                                music-widget
canon-eos-utility                                               nordic-nrf-command-line-tools
capacities                                                      nozbe
carbide-create                                                  oak9
chatbox                                                         obs-advanced-scene-switcher
codeedit                                                        obsbot-webcam
command-x                                                       opal
concept2-utility                                                openbb-terminal
copilot                                                         openrocket
corsair-icue                                                    orbstack
craft                                                           orcaslicer
creative                                                        pallotron-yubiswitch
cursor                                                          philips-hue-sync
dadroit-json-viewer                                             piclist
ddpm                                                            picoscope
dehelper                                                        picoscope
devpod                                                          pololu-avr-programmer-v2
dintch                                                          prism
displaylink                                                     processmonitor
doppler                                                         prolific-pl2303
drata-agent                                                     qflipper
drata-agent                                                     qmk-toolbox
droidcam-obs                                                    red-canary-mac-monitor
dymo-label                                                      reminders-menubar
easydict                                                        rewind
edrawmind                                                       ricoh-theta
elgato-camera-hub                                               rio
elgato-control-center                                           rio
elgato-game-capture-hd                                          rode-connect
elgato-stream-deck                                              rsyncui
elgato-video-capture                                            saleae-logic
elgato-wave-link                                                samsung-portable-ssd-t7
elk                                                             score
engine-dj                                                       score
entry                                                           segger-jlink
eobcanka                                                        shureplus-motiv
eset-cyber-security                                             silicon-labs-vcp-driver
eu                                                              simpleclock
eusamanager                                                     skiff
fightcade                                                       smooze-pro
filemonitor                                                     sonos
firefly-shimmer                                                 sony-ps-remote-play
focusrite-control                                               stack
focusrite-saffire-mixcontrol                                    steelseries-engine
fractal-bot                                                     steelseries-gg
frappe-books                                                    submariner
ftdi-vcp-driver                                                 synology-cloud-station-backup
fujitsu-scansnap-home                                           synology-drive
fx-cast-bridge                                                  synology-photo-station-uploader
garmin-express                                                  synology-surveillance-station-client
genesys-cloud                                                   synologyassistant
gitkraken-cli                                                   tachidesk-sorayomi
graalvm-jdk                                                     tastytrade
grs-bluewallet                                                  tea
gutenprint                                                      ths
hdhomerun                                                       ths
hp-easy-start                                                   tiptoi-manager
huiontablet                                                     toshiba-color-mfp
hummingbird                                                     tuist
iconchamp                                                       ubiquiti-unifi-controller
imazing-converter                                               uhk-agent
insta360-studio                                                 ultimate-vocal-remover
irpf2023                                                        usmart-trade
jabra-direct                                                    vbrokers
karafun                                                         volta
kiibohd-configurator                                            wacom-tablet
konica-minolta-bizhub-c750i-driver                              wch-ch34x-usb-serial-driver
konica-minolta-bizhub-c759-c658-c368-c287-c3851-driver          worldpainter
lasso                                                           xtool-creative-space
lg-onscreen-control                                             yealink-meeting
linn-konfig                                                     yubico-authenticator
llamachat                                                       yubico-yubikey-manager
lo-rain                                                         zed
logi-options-plus                                               zsa-wally

You have 174 outdated formulae and 3 outdated casks installed.
==> Migrating formula postgresql to postgresql@14
==> Unlinking postgresql
==> Moving postgresql versions to /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@14
==> Relinking postgresql@14
Warning: postgresql@14 is outdated!
To avoid broken installations, as soon as possible please run:
  brew upgrade
Or, if you're OK with a less reliable fix:
  brew upgrade postgresql@14


The 4.0.26 changelog can be found at:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases/tag/4.0.26
==> Fetching dependencies for csvkit: ca-certificates, openssl@3, sqlite, xz and python@3.11
==> Fetching ca-certificates
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ca-certificates/manifests/2023-05-30
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ca-certificates/blobs/sha256:f664c0f185677a82689ada2a4e35c555e48885e6c2fb5e2d
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Fetching openssl@3
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/3/manifests/3.1.1_1
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/3/blobs/sha256:50c7448f726762394d63abe2722acee2a426d8fd1a8101504ad7c8
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Fetching sqlite
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/sqlite/manifests/3.42.0
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/sqlite/blobs/sha256:f0ccc2c64cc793a160be644fbb654074f42750735488702169a1353d3
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Fetching xz
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/xz/manifests/5.4.3
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/xz/blobs/sha256:cc402684eb7e9e81ea12b8721078c8fa1d36f2edd7ce41d0835282c00197f
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Fetching python@3.11
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/python/3.11/manifests/3.11.4_1
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/python/3.11/blobs/sha256:aeaf5d77ce1aad2cd39e7acebb78076bd0417459ff4825e1377a
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Fetching csvkit
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/csvkit/manifests/1.1.1
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/csvkit/blobs/sha256:61a24baa066b0a81133629e7dd9b3f1932ee6adefc96a0043881f657c
####################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Installing dependencies for csvkit: ca-certificates, openssl@3, sqlite, xz and python@3.11
==> Installing csvkit dependency: ca-certificates
==> Pouring ca-certificates--2023-05-30.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Regenerating CA certificate bundle from keychain, this may take a while...
  /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/2023-05-30: 3 files, 216.2KB
==> Installing csvkit dependency: openssl@3
==> Pouring openssl@3--3.1.1_1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/opt/openssl
Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try running `brew upgrade` and after that `brew install csvkit`?

This can solve your issues because there are many more outdated software versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be networking issue

```
$ curl -I https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
HTTP/2 200
server: GitHub.com
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Beside install from API (which would download the json index file), can you also install directly from the formula spec, by using `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install csvkit` (I would give this a go)

Ultimately, you can run `brew doctor` to do the sanity check.

If still no good, can you update OP with `brew config` information?

Comment: Hi, Please find "brew config" as an edit to my question.

Comment: @dave, did you try `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install csvkit`?

Comment: Added an edit with the output to the above command, TL;DR -- it is "Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/opt/openssl"

Answer (score 0):

{
"previousPageCursor": null,
"nextPageCursor": null,
"data": [
{
"userAssetId": 413511366,
"serialNumber": null,
"assetId": 1028606,
"name": "Red Baseball Cap",
"recentAveragePrice": 271,
"originalPrice": null,
"assetStock": null,
"buildersClubMembershipType": 0
},
{
"userAssetId": 1075234337,
"serialNumber": 820,
"assetId": 93131552,
"name": "Dark Conjurer",
"recentAveragePrice": 59910,
"originalPrice": 250,
"assetStock": 900,
"buildersClubMembershipType": 0
},
{
"userAssetId": 4506314814,
"serialNumber": 944,
"assetId": 439946101,
"name": "Adurite King of the Night ",
"recentAveragePrice": 9805,
"originalPrice": 100,
"assetStock": 2000,
"buildersClubMembershipType": 0
},
{
"userAssetId": 4779382222,
"serialNumber": null,
"assetId": 71484026,
"name": "Sinister Branches",
"recentAveragePrice": 2223,
"originalPrice": 125,
"assetStock": null,
"buildersClubMembershipType": 0
},
{
"userAssetId": 20445168513,
"serialNumb
er": 4667,
"assetId": 1609401184,
"name": "Supa Dupa Fly Cap",
"recentAveragePrice": 5488,
"originalPrice": 1000,
"assetStock": 10000,
"buildersClubMembershipType": 0
}
]
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).